# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a poorly normalized set of tables and I am trying to correct this issue. The DB is MS SQL 2005.

Table1 has an `id` field (record ID), a `mainID` field (person ID) and a `sequence` field (and int that determines the sort order)

Table2 has its own `id` field and a copy of the id for the first record by a person (`sequence` = 1).

I've added a new field to table2 call table2_id and I would like to populate this field with the ID from table2 so that I can do away with `table1.mainID`. table2 only has a record for one of the records for each person and `mainId` is set to the id where `table1.sequence = 1`.

This is the update query I thought would do the job by I'm getting errors

```
update table1 as a  
set regInfoID = (select b.id 
                 from table2 as b 
                 where b.ref1 = (select c.id 
                                 from table1 as c 
                                 where c.mainID = a.mainID 
                                       and sequence = 1))
```

I believe I'm on the right track her since the following query works fine

```
select regInfoID = (select b.id 
                    from table2 as b 
                    where b.ref1 = (select c.id 
                                    from table1 as c 
                                    where c.mainID = a.mainID 
                                          and sequence = 1)), a.*  
from table1 as a
```

Comment: MS SQL 2005 and the error msg is   
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2   
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your query is equivalent to this:

```
update a
set regInfoID = b.id
-- select a.*, b.id
from table2 b 
inner join table1 c on c.id = b.ref1
inner join table1 a on c.mainID = a.mainID and c.sequence = 1
```

From this query, I think you will potentially have indeterminate results because table2 (b) is not guaranteed to be a single row result.  So regInfoID will be set to one of the resulting b.id values.

Comment: I never thought of writing an update query using this style before. I verified that table2 was indeed a one to many before i started working on the update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, no prob.  This form works well because I can write the select statement first, to see what the results would look like, then just replace the SELECT with the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
update table1
set regInfoID = (select b.id 
                 from table2 as b 
                 where b.ref1 = (select c.id 
                                 from table1 as c 
                                 where c.mainID = a.mainID 
                                       and sequence = 1)) 
from table1 as a
```

The error seems to have been cause by my having the alia in the update statement instead of in a from statement.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: yup, that's all it was. if you want an alias, you need to use the `FROM` clause. It's non-ANSI standard, btw. FWIW, also see my example using a CTE. this form keeps me sane.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using your SELECT statement that works, and wrapping it in a CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select a.*, _regInfoID = (select b.id 
                        from table2 as b 
                        where b.ref1 = (select c.id 
                                        from table1 as c 
                                        where c.mainID = a.mainID 
                                              and sequence = 1))
    from table1 as a 
    )
update cte set regInfoID = _regInfoID
```

I like this style, since you can preview your modifications before applying them, and it's trivial to turn the `SELECT` into an `UPDATE`

But the problem you had with the original query was just a syntax error. This is how it should have been written. Note the `FROM table1 AS a`:

```
update a 
set regInfoID = (select b.id 
                 from table2 as b 
                 where b.ref1 = (select c.id 
                                 from table1 as c 
                                 where c.mainID = a.mainID 
                                       and sequence = 1))  
from table1 as a
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yea it was as easy as adding the alias to the from statement. This is ultimately what I figured out was the problem. I'm going to give this one to Jeff Meatball Yang since he beat you by 7 mins and I think his reworking of the query is way tighter then my original.